# On which unix distributions is Python installed as part of the default install?

Tags: python, portability

Does anyone know of an overview that would document on which (recent) UNIX distributions Python is available by default, i.e. part of the default installation?

PS: Answers from StackOverflow, before the question was moved here:

- Don't know for all Unix OSes, but for Linux you can always check distrowatch.org. But this is not the right site to post this kind of question: please move this to unix.stackexchange.com – vstrien 2 hours ago
- I can't think of any distributions where it isn't installed by default. Many basic system tools are written in Python these days. – Daniel Roseman 1 hour ago
- It is NOT installed by default in LFS... – Oz123 1 hour ago

Comment: *"NOT installed by default in LFS"* Well, that's what you'd expect from a (meta)distribution that has *nothing* installed by default, right? LFS is about building *everything* on your own. No "by default" apps. No "by default" GUI. Just *bare core system*.

Comment: I agree with @rozcietrzewiacz but I would like to add that I don't really consider LFS a "distribution", since they're not distributing anything but instructions and a few patches; as I recall, you download the sources from the projects' web sites directly.

Comment: Good point, @Kevin. I couldn't find a better word, so I called it a *(meta)distribution*, as Gentoo calls itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just looking at the systems available to me here:

- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://www.redhat.com/) and its close relatives ([Fedora](https://getfedora.org/), [CentOS](http://centos.org/), [Scientific Linux](http://www.scientificlinux.org/), [Oracle Linux](http://www.oracle.com/us/linux/)...) will always have Python installed since the installer and many core tools are written in Python.
- [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/) has had Python installed by default since at least version 8.04.
- [Debian](http://debian.org/) currently ships with Python installed by default.
- [Mac OS X](http://www.apple.com/macosx/) has shipped with Python installed by default going back to at least 10.3.
- [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org/) currently ships with Python installed by default. I assume that means Solaris also does, but I do not have a system here to test.

Python is not installed by default in any of the BSDs, unless you count OS X. You may well find that it is available on a BSD system because it was added after the system was installed. If not, it is available through the default package system in all cases:

- [FreeBSD](http://freebsd.org/) includes Python in the Ports system: `/usr/ports/lang/python`
- [OpenBSD](http://openbsd.org/) includes Python in its package system: `sudo pkg_add python`
- [NetBSD](http://netbsd.org/) includes Python in its [`pkgsrc`](http://netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/) system, in `lang/python*`

Comment: Solaris 10 and 11 definitely include python in their default installation. Python is even a mandatory component in  the latter given the fact various tools are relying on it including the new packaging commands (pkg, packagemanager, ...) and the boot environment administration cli (beadm).

Comment: I can confirm Oracle Solaris 11 comes with Python installed by default (version 2.6.4)

Comment: this is interesting for me, because I think about moving from perl towards python. I'm looking at the official docker containerimages: Ubuntu/Debian ship with perl but not python ; Centos does neither (it has pydoc and pyenv?!) ; Fedora has python3.7 and no perl. Maybe anyone knows when/if python will ship with default containers?

Comment: **Manjaro** also has Python in its default install (although I don't know about **Arch Linux**, from which it is derived).

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Roseman got it right, i think *all* major distributions have python installed by default as its used for many (if not most) applications for the Gnome/KDE desktop enviroments (at least).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786693/is-python-on-every-gnu-linux-distribution/6786804#6786804) on a similar question on StackOverflow.

Also, [this page](http://docs.python.org/using/unix.html) of the Python documentation, says pratically the same thing:

> Python comes preinstalled on most Linux distributions, and is available as a package on all others.

Comment: X windows, let alone Gnome or KDE, is not installed by default on any serious server dist'n.  If you have a box serving some vanilla LAMP site, you are rather likely not to have any use for Python.

Answer (score 3):

On **[Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/)**, Python is one of the very few things that *need* to be contained in an install, because its core package management system, **[portage](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=1)**, is written in Python+bash.